# How to get two-directional Animations in Android?

Tags: android, transition, android-pendingintent

im trying a little bit in programming android.

So now to my Situation:

I've got two Activities that should be connetced by Intents. When i switch from activity 1 (by clicking a button), I've made an animation files and overriden the transition, so that activity 1 slides out to the left and activity 2 slides in from the right.

How is it possible to make the following: when i push a button in activity 2, the activity slide shall be the other way around, so that the activity 2 slides out to the right and activity one slides in from the right.

my code looks for the animation looks as following:

slide_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
      android:fromXDelta="100%p" 
      android:toXDelta="0%p">
</translate
```

>

slide_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
      android:fromXDelta="0" 
      android:toXDelta="-100%p">
</translate>
```

and that's my code of the intent that starts activity 2:

```
Intent i = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slid_in, R.anim.slid_out);
```

What do I have to do in the other intent, from act.2 to act.1?

Thank you for helping me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make 2 new XMLs, simply reverse the first ones,
slide_in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
      android:fromXDelta="-100%p" 
      android:toXDelta="0%p">
</translate>
```

slide_out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" 
      android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
      android:toXDelta="100%p">
</translate>
```

And in your activity2 change intent to this

```
Intent i = new Intent(Second.this, First.class);
                startActivity(i);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the excellent library from [Jack Wharton](http://profiles.google.com/jakewharton): [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)

More easy to use, compatible with any Android version from Froyo (you will be able to use new classes added in HoneyComb), and more.

```
AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
set.playTogether(
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationX", 0, 360),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotationY", 0, 180),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "rotation", 0, -90),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "translationX", 0, 90),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "translationY", 0, 90),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleX", 1, 1.5f),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "scaleY", 1, 0.5f),
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myView, "alpha", 1, 0.25f, 1));
set.setDuration(5 * 1000).start();
```